passkeys not working under win11 when not in vpn (something went wrong)
I am trying to implement passkey authentication at my company. We use Keycloak, but we encounter the same issue on https://www.passkeys.io/.
Here's the strange part: when I am at the company building, it doesn't work—we get the infamous "something went wrong" popup during the registration process. However, when we are at home using VPN, everything works fine. Another oddity is that it works on Windows 10 but not on Windows 11.
current system is windows 11 23H2
Here is what we have tried so far:

Deactivated Credential Guard
Used Wireshark to check Bluetooth packets (results were the same in both cases, meaning we got the same packets sent in BLE working or not)
Reviewed all possible event logs but found nothing
Checked the proxy settings, although it should not be involved
Tested on both https://www.passkeys.io/ and a local Keycloak instance (same behavior)
search on internet...

A detail description of the comportment

opening chrome on https://www.passkeys.io/
click on the "don't have an account?"
entering an email and clicking on continue
click on continue on the create a passkey screen
the popup for using a phone appeared clicking next
reading the qr code with my phone
validating something on my phone
after some times less than 10 seconds a popup appeared saying "something went wrong"

we test this on apple and android phones, it does not work.
if we use the bitwarden app it works.
Has anyone else encountered this type of problem and found a solution?

The problem at work sounds like an issue only the network administrator can resolve. Passkeys works flawlessly on every Windows 10 and Windows 11 machine I have access to. How Windows handles Passkeys natively in Windows 11 23H2 is very different than Windows 10 22H2. I use a browser extension to handle my Passkeys.

I should have added that it works everywhere with the browser extension (bitwarden for my case), we got the problem only when using a phone (apple or android) and BLE

We cannot help you with an issue that is only happening on mobile phones or are you saying you only run into this problem when your passkey is stored on the mobile phone and your PC is unable to retrieve it? Your last comment isn't clear, and if you should have mentioned it, you should [edit] your question.  Regardless, I have access to a half dozen machines, and have zero problems with Passkeys.

I edited my post, hope it will give some more clarification
